# parallel installation of different ocaml versions

Tags: compilation, ocaml, xml-rpc

I'm attempting to compile the [adder example](http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpc-light/source/browse/trunk/examples/adder/?r=151) of the [xml-rpc-light](http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpc-light/) ocaml package. After including (I suspect all) the necessary libraries I get this error at compilation:

```
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Files /[...]/godi/lib/ocaml/site-lib/xmlrpc-light/xmlrpc-light.cma(XmlRpcBase64)
       and /[...]/godi/lib/ocaml/std-lib/stdlib.cma(Buffer)
       make inconsistent assumptions over interface Buffer
Command exited with code 2.
```

I understand what it means. Basically, somehow, xmlrpc-light.cma and stdlib.cma don't assume the same Buffer interface and this gives a type error at compilation time. But how can I reconcile them without changing the code of these libraries?

### Edit after Ygrek's and Gasche's answers

From both answers I think I know what the problem is now but I'm not really sure how to deal with it. I use GODI and everything usually compiles there (3.11.2 version). More recently, I installed OCaml 3.12 independently just to play with it. Now, if I go to a new command line and write `ocaml`, it is this new 3.12 which starts up. Presently, within GODI everything still works as usual (or almost -- see below) but if I want to install some non-GODI library (like xmlrpc-light) I have to use the command line. If I try to compile xmlrpc-light using `make`, I get:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package xml-light,netclient,nethttpd-for-netcgi2 -c XmlRpc.mli
File "XmlRpc.mli", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: /[...]/godi/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/xml-light/xml.cmi
is not a compiled interface
make[1]: *** [XmlRpc.cmi] Error 2
make: *** [native-code-library] Error 2
```

The reason why it is looking into GODI libraries here, despite the fact that the ocaml available at command line is the non-GODI 3.12, is that `ocamlfind` actually calls `/[...]/godi/bin/ocamlfind`. I can understand why 3.12 ocaml complaints about xml.cmi not being a compiled interface (it was compiled with GODI -- 3.11.2).

So, to sum up, my system is currently a mess. And I don't know how to keep the two ocaml environments (GODI and 3.12) and select each time which one I want to use. But I'm happy to remove 3.12 if it solves all my problems.

#### Problem with GODI

Just to give some more information, I've recently tried to add the `godi-ocaml-xml-rpc` library (because it's an alternative xml-rpc library and it's available in GODI), but I get

```
> ocamlfind ocamlopt -a -o xmlrpc.cmxa \
>   -predicates "" xmlRPCTypes.cmx xmlRPCDtd.cmx xmlRPCNet.cmx xmlRPCClient.cmx xmlRPCServer.cmx cgiSource.cmx  
> ocamlfind ocamlopt -o oxridl.opt -package "pcre annexlib" -linkpkg oxridl.ml
> cd /[...]/godi/build/godi/godi-ocaml-xml-rpc/work/ocaml-xml-rpc-0.2.6/httpd && make && make opt
> ocamlfind ocamlc -c -I .. httpdSource.mli -package "http annexlib"
> File "httpdSource.mli", line 1, characters 0-1:
> Error: ../xmlRPCServer.cmi
> is not a compiled interface
> make[7]: *** [httpdSource.cmi] Error 2
> Error: Exec error: File /[...]/godi/build/godi/godi-ocaml-xml-rpc/./makefile, line 38: Command returned with non-zero exit code
> Error: Exec error: File /[...]/godi/build/godi/godi-ocaml-xml-rpc/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1378: Command returned with non-zero exit code

### Error: Command fails with code 1: godi_console
```

which I suspect could have to do with the same problem. The weird thing is that it's complaining about `xmlRPCServer.cmi` not being a compiled interface when, I think, it is precisely one of the files it should be compiling to install godi-ocaml-xml-rpc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the single version of ocaml compiler and rebuild xmlrpc.

UPDATE

Easy rule of thumb - have separate ocamlfind for each ocaml installation and make sure that only one ocaml + ocamlfind are in PATH at any point of time. i.e. install ocaml-3.12 into `/opt/ocaml-3.12` and install fresh ocamlfind into `/opt/ocaml-3.12/bin` too. Then when you want to use ocaml 3.12 just use `PATH=/opt/ocaml-3.12/bin:$PATH` and it will pick up ocamlfind and matching ocaml and all ocamlfind installations will be separated from system ocaml. The old ocaml install will not be affected at all.

(One can go with single ocamlfind and many ocaml installs but that's more complicated and I wouldn't recommend it - ocamlfind builds quickly anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edited my answer and added some more information. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks! I did have two separate ocamlfinds in there. The problem was that everything was in the PATH and it was using the ocamlfind from one and the ocaml installation from the other as you pointed out. All sorted!

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on ygrek answer : that probably means that xmlrpc-light has been compiled against a different version of the standard library (.. than the one available on your system). This is possible if you reinstalled a new standard library since you installed xmlrpc-light, or if you use a binary xmlrpc-light package that was compiled for a different system. The solution is probably to rebuild xmlrpc against your current standard library.

Those interface versioning issues are delicate because they don't correspond to what is the custom in C/C++ interface decisions; in those languages, when a package interface change, it is assumed by default to be compatible with the previous interface. In OCaml, they are assumed to be incompatible (they compare a hash of the whole module interface), and recompilation is mandatory.

Most packaging tools, e.g. for GNU/Linux distributions, assume the compatible-by-default behavior, and don't have the tooling in place to ensure recompilation when an interface changes. GODI, which was designed specifically for OCaml, does that dependency tracking (if you upgrade a package in GODI, it will recompile all dependent packages), and the Debian packaging team has a scheme in place to achieve the same behaviour with their packaging system (for more details about this, see the article [Enforcing Type-Safe Linking using Inter-Package Relationships](http://wiki.debian.org/Teams/OCamlTaskForce?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=jfla10-dh-ocaml.pdf)). Some other tools are careful about this, but unfortunately this is not the norm, and you may still have such errors using only the package manager of your distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edited my answer and added some more information. Any thoughts?